# Select2 should not send ajax if the search text is just empty spaces. How to achieve that?

Tags: jquery-select2, select2-rails

I have a scenario where I shouldn't show any results when the user searches with empty spaces. How to achieve it. Is there any way to validate and search in select2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `query` to accomplish that:

```
$("#select2-input").select2({
    query: function(options) {

        if(options.term.replace(/ /g, "").length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'tags',
                data: { q : options.term },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(data) {
                    options.callback({results: data.result});
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Note that

> In order for this function to work Select2 should be attached to a input type='hidden' tag instead of a select.

This might have some quirks, but that really depends on how you are using Select2.